# Healpy: cut n by n pix submaps

Tags: healpy

I have a healpy full-sky map, and need to chose some sky patches centered around given pixels. `hp.query_disc` finds the pixels within a given disc, which is nice. But I would like to be able to add/subtract on different sky patches, and so the fact that different discs cannot be the same size causes a problem.

I have also used

`hp.gnomview(return_projected_map=True)`

to look at my sky patches, and found that each returned 2D array has the same size. However since I would probably do stuff on many submaps, I do not want the maps to be drawn every time. Is it possible to obtain only the 2D array? And if so, is it fine to use `plt.imshow` after adding/subtracting those arrays?

I feel like there should be more elegant ways to achieve what I want -- Are there any existing routines that I overlooked? Thanks!